# 2 Actions in One activity

Tags: java, android

I have an `Activity` with `WebView` and a `Button`.

I want to go to next `Activity` when i press a `Button` but I don't know how.

When user clicks a `Button`, he will be "teleported" to `MainActivity`.
I have a problem.

[image]

[image]

It's marked at red color.
I don't know how to do this.
Can somebody give me answer with example and correct my code?

There is code:

```
  package musial.pzstis.com.pzstiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main10Activity extends Activity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main10);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView6);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://pzstiz.swiebodzin.pl/zastepstwa/PZSTiZ_zastepstwa.pdf");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.setInitialScale(190);
        myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    Button button2;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Main10Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to create a new Activity. You can't have 2 onCreate methodos in one class.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have 2 OnCreate() methods in activity. Delete 2nd oncreate() method and copy the code written in 2nd onCreate() into 1st onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two onCreate in the same activity.

```
 package musial.pzstis.com.pzstiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main10Activity extends Activity {

private WebView myWebView;
private Button button2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main10);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView6);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://pzstiz.swiebodzin.pl/zastepstwa/PZSTiZ_zastepstwa.pdf");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.setInitialScale(190);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
     button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Main10Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}